# How can I implement a controller action that can consume requests with both text/plain and application/type?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

Here is my current implementation:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("test")]
    [Consumes("application/json", "text/plain")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestWebhook([FromBody] JsonElement payload)
    {
        return Ok(await ProcessInput(payload));
    }
```

When I call this endpoint with `Content-Type: application/json` it works as expected. When I call it with `Content-Type: text/plain` I get the below error:

> {
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
> "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
> "status": 415,
> "traceId": "00-bb0276f3ec28fb468dc36b3856fba038-58a520bb56d41841-00" }

How can I configure my action to consume both content types properly?

Thanks,

Comment: remove [Consumes("application/json", "text/plain")] it is irrelevant. Since you use [FromBody] it  only expects json input

Comment: @Serge So is it impossible to accept both content types somehow?

Comment: I am not sure, maybe there is a hack. read this https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2020/02/29/asp-net-core-how-to-make-a-controller-endpoint-that-accepts-text-plain/. But I don't like JElement as an input parameter class. I am afraid it will accept  only json

Comment: Yes, this helped a lot. I went by this way. Thanks